# ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() does not seem to work

Tags: java, android

When I add or remove object from a `List<T>`, I call `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to "rerender" the `ListView`, but it does not work...

**Activity:**

```
    private ListView lv_course; //Liste des matières
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
    private CustomListAdapterCourse customListAdapterCourse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_course);

        courses = getDataFromDatabase();

        lv_course = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_course);
        customListAdapterCourse = new CustomListAdapterCourse(this, courses);
        lv_course.setAdapter(customListAdapterCourse);

        //...

    }
```

**Adapter:**

```
private Context context;
private List<Course> courses;

public CustomListAdapterCourse(Context theContext, List<Course> theListCourses) {
    super(theContext, 0, theListCourses);
    this.context = theContext;
    this.courses = theListCourses;
}
```

In an other activity, I add data in database, and during the `onResume()` :

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        courses = getDataFromDatabase();
        customListAdapterCourse.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

The `ListView` is not updated, but when I close the app and rerun it, it contains all objects I have created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't adding any new data to your adapter.  You need to call `.add()`

```
customListAdapterCourse.add(your_new_data);
```

then there will actually be changes to register when you call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
customListAdapterCourse.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Depending on your adapter type you can also use `loadObjects()` to cause a refresh of your data.  This may cause another query to be made for data (again, depending on your adapter type) if you are aware that a change has been made to a database and would like to reflect those changes in your dataset/listview.  This would be used if you don't require the use of `add()` or `remove()`

`customListAdapterCourse.loadObjects();`

But since it appears that you are actually loading `courses` into the adapter this might not apply and you are better off with `add()`.

```
customListAdapterCourse.add(your_new_data_row);
customListAdapterCourse.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You can also add a bunch of items at once with:

```
customListAdapterCourse.addAll(array_of_new_objects);
customListAdapterCourse.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not updating your adapter's data, you're just changing the reference to the object, but the reference in your adapter points to the older object.

Either instantiate a new adapter with the new object or add a method inside your adapter to change your data.